# BeanIO - UnidentifiedRecordException when parsing UTF8 file

Tags: java, parsing, utf-8, bean-io

I have a problem when parsing a file that is encoded with UTF8.

I have two files which are completely identical, except for their encoding. (I simply just copied the file and saved it with UTF8, so the contents are identical). One is encoded using ANSI, the other with UTF8. The file which is encoded with ANSI is succesfully parsed while the other file causes BeanIO to throw an UnidentifiedRecordException when calling the BeanReader.read() method:

```
org.beanio.UnidentifiedRecordException: Unidentified record at line 1
```

I have tried to solve this by explicitly setting the encoding to UTF8 using this code:

```
public static BeanReader getBeanReader(File file, StreamBuilder builder) {
     StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
     factory.define(builder);
     InputStream iStream;
     try {
         iStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         throw new CustomException("Could not create BeanReader, file not found", e);
     }
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(iStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     return factory.createReader("reader", reader);
}
```

which doesn't solve the issue.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

As the first line is claimed erroneous, did you save the UTF-8 **without BOM** (that infamous zero-width space at file start)?

Comment: Tried to save the file as UTF 8 without BOM now, and that worked. But why doesn't the BeanReader recognise the BOM sequence at the beginning when I set the charset to be UTF 8? I have also some other problems related to this which can't be solved by changing the encoding manually on a file, so I was more interested in whether this is a bug in BeanIO or if there is another way to solve this.

Comment: Some parsers, i.e. XML parsers, do not recognize a BOM as whitespace. Here a "record" start is expected. And a BOM (besides being a pure Unicode superfluous artefact) is such a special case, and even invisible to human eyes.